# Activate conda environment inside Singularity container

Tags: bash, conda, singularity-container

So, I guess this is done in a really simple way, but I do not have experience with it, so I do not understand what is the issue. Let's say I have a conda environment `example_env` and a Singularity image `example.simg`.

I can run the image:
`singularity run --nv /mnt/appl/singularity_images/pytorch-19.03-py3.simg`

Once I am in the Singularity container, I can write `conda activate example_env`, and it works for me without any problem.

Now, I want to switch from the interactive section to a script. So, instead of using `singularity run` and entering the interactive shell, I have tried `singularity exec`: `singularity exec example.simg bash scripts/train.sh`, where `train.sh` contains only one (just for now, of course) command: `conda activate example_env`.

However, now it does not work, and gives me the following error: `CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'. To initialize your shell, run $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>` If I try to follow the error message, and add the `conda init` command, it does not help.

What is wrong, and how can I run `conda activate` with `singularity exec`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you run the echo commands as shown in this stackoverflow.
I think you should check out the following.

[Activate conda environment on execution of Singularity container in Nextflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56446195/activate-conda-environment-on-execution-of-singularity-container-in-nextflow)

Comment: To be honest, I do not really understand how to use that answer in my situation, but adding a line from https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7980 solved my issue. (`source ~/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh`)